# Spelt model name wrong ruby on rails, is there a command line way to correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used

`rails generate model Suject`

when I should have spelt it

`Subject`

Is there a quicker way to correct this than delete all the files?

Answer (score 2):

You can not rename this as it already created migration also for this. If you want to do this you need to manually change each file created by command and it's name also.

But you can simply destroy and generate new.

`rails destroy model Suject`

and then

`rails generate model Subject`

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you are using git (which you should), why not just run:

```
git reset --hard
rails g model Subject
```

?

Comment: too strong, Rails have in-built destroy generator.